# Is there a way to tell if a page load was done inside a frame, iframe, etc.?

Tags: fraud-detection

Wondering if there's a way to detect a page load was done inside a frame, iframe, etc. (likely via JavaScript) and if so, what are the limits of such a detection system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (top.location.href != window.location.href) {
     alert("In A Frame");
}
```

The limit is if JavaScript is turned off it won't work.

You can also use the [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/the_x-frame-options_response_header) HTTP header. This header tells a web browser whether or not to allow a web page to be framed in another web page. This includes `<frame>` and `<iframe>` tags.

There are two possible values for this header:

**DENY** - This setting prevents any pages served from being placed in a frame even if it is on the same website it originates from. should be used if you never intend for your pages to be used inside of a frame.

**SAMEORIGIN** - This setting allows pages to be served in a frame of a page on the same website. If an external site attempts to load the page in a frame the request will be denied.

This header works in Internet Explorer 8.0, Firefox 3.6.9, Opera 10.50, Safari 4.0, and Chrome 4.1.

Comment: @blunder, No problem. Try using the header I just added, too, as it is a better way to do it and will compliment the JavaScript code nicely. (Assuming you are trying to block the content from being loaded in a frame that is).

Comment: Thanks, John -- I had wondered if there was a header based detection system, selecting you as the answer. Cheers!

Comment: Note that the `X-Frame-Options` header may prevent some legitimate services such as Google Translate from working. See the following for further info: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31287/is-there-any-good-reason-i-would-want-my-website-to-be-framed